# How to take a backup of infopath and restoring infopath in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, forms-services

I have created a list form and published to my site using InfoPath. Now I want to edit this form. But, before that I want to take the backup of this form for safe side.

So that if there are any issues with the updated infopath, I can restore the previous version of form.

Is there any way to do this, or any article that describes the process of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

In on prem it works but please test it before on SPOnline. You can save the list as template and it will preserve the IP form, include the data and if anything goes wrong you can recreate the list from the template (you can download template locally as well) if you use lookup fields you will need to reconnect them after recreating the list.

Comment: Is saving a list as template will save the list data also ?

Comment: Yes if you say it so; when creating the template mark the check box to include data.

Comment: Not recommended if list data is huge. If not then you can give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the form as if you are going to edit it, but first save a copy of it locally before applying any changes. That will become your backup copy of the form. Then go back to your form and save it as the new version (different name) and start editing it as you'd like. Personally I save my infopath forms with the title and add a number to the end so I know what "version" I'm working with locally.

To download the latest version of your infopath form, from a list, you can go to settings-->form settings